# create form manually using notepad

Tags: java

how to create a login form using the Java programming language
   Manually? because i'm try to create form login and menu not using netbeans or eclipse.
    (this is the exampe source code)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Login extends JFrame{
    String tampilkan;

    Login(){
        JFrame jf= new JFrame();

        jf.setTitle("Pemesanan");
        jf.setLocation(300, 150);
        jf.setSize(500,150);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 30));

        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Login"));


        JPanel pane1 = new JPanel();        
        pane1.setLayout (new GridLayout(1,2));


        JPanel pane2 = new JPanel();
        pane2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        pane2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));

        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("User Name :");
        JTextField txt1 = new JTextField("");

        JLabel lbl2 = new  JLabel("Password :");
        JPasswordField pass2 = new JPasswordField("");

        JButton btnCancel =new JButton("Cancel");
        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");

        pane.add(lbl1);
        pane.add(txt1);

        pane.add(lbl2);
        pane.add(pass2);

        pane1.add(btnCancel);
        pane1.add(btnLogin);

        jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //menambahkan panel ke dalam frame sesuai dengan layout
        jf.getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jf.getContentPane().add(pane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        //tampilkan JFrame/Windows/Frame 
        jf.setVisible(true);

        tampilkan.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                tampil(e); 
            }
        });

        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                btnLoginActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });


        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java ActionEvent e) {
                btnCancelActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });

    }   
}
```

Comment: What issue are you having specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input, you might simply add the following to your class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Login();
}
```

in order to get that JFrame on your screen. Meaning: you already have code that that creates a window with input fields and so on.

Side note on code quality: you do **everything** within your constructor. That is the exact opposite on how you should do it - a constructor should do as few things as possible. At least, you would want to move all that code into some private methods of your class.